# request options with expect in node mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js

I want to provide custom headers in my unit test and currently my unit test is

```
request(sails.hooks.http.app)
  .post('/myurl')
  .send(userDetails)
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect(200)
  .end(function (err, res) {
    if(err) throw err;
    //do something
});
```

I want to add headers like

```
var options = {
  url: 'community',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken 
  }
};
```

When i see the docs of request in npmjs. It asks me to provide options to request as

```
request(options, callback);
```

How do I provide custom headers in my case ie if I provide req parameters as options object in my unittest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `supertest` has a `set()` to set request headers:

```
request(sails.hooks.http.app)
  .post('/myurl')
  .set('Authorization', 'value')
  .send(userDetails)
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect(200)
```